# In angularjs, using ngOptions, how do I get both the object from the array being iterated over and its index in the array

Tags: angularjs-ng-options

Looks like it's possible from this:

"Using 'select as' will bind the result of the select expression to the model, but the value of the `<select>` and `<option>` html elements will be either the index (for array data sources) or property name (for object data sources) of the value within the collection"

But I can't figure out how to get 'the value of the `<select>` tag'

Comment: That got garbled. The quote is:

Comment: Again, the quote is: "Using 'select as' will bind the result of the select expression to the model, but the value of the &lt;select&gt;and &lt;option&gt;html elements will be either the index (for array data sources) or property name (for object data sources) of the value within the collection"

Comment: and what I can't figure out is how to get 'the value of the &lt;select&gt; tag

Comment: have you inspected the angularJS source code? you will get a better idea about what is supported in the ng-options directive.